# How to set animation repeatedly for labels which placed inside the uitableviewcel?l

Tags: ios, animation, uitableview, uilabel

Hi I need to set fade in fade out animation for a label which i placed inside each tableviewcell. This animation should call every 5 secs. So i gave the animation inside cellForRowAtIndexPath. But this animation should occur continuously.I tried by putting it in nstimer but that animation occurs only for label which present in last row. So now i gave inside cellForRowAtIndexPath. As of now animation is coming for all labels but it occurs only while calling cellforrowatindexpath.Please guide me.This is my code which i gave outside the cell creation of cellforrowatindexpath

```
        UILabel *rewardPtLabel = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:kRewardlabelTag];
    rewardPtLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[appRecord objectForKey:@"ProductReward"],@""];//rewardPoints

     rewardPtLabel.alpha = 0;
     rewardPtLabel.textColor=[UIColor redColor];
     [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
     [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
     [UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
     rewardPtLabel.alpha = 1;
     [UIView commitAnimations];

     rewardPtLabel.textColor=[UIColor greenColor];
     [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
     [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
     [UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
     rewardPtLabel.alpha = 0;
     [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 0):

Only setup the animation **once** per label. That means not in every cellForRow: call, but only at the cell creation time. Or alternatively remove the animation before, but that's a little bit ugly.
`[view.layer removeAllAnimations]`

1) You should use the block based animation methods, if you are on iOS 4 or later. (What you're hopefully are), see `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:`

2) Look at the animation option `UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat` for repeated animations

3) Also see `UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse` so you only need to setup the fade in one direction..

This will result in much less code and work better.

Comment: i gave this but still it is animating only once               [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 
        delay:0.0 
      options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut 
      animations:^ {
       appointmentDisplayLbl.alpha = 1.0;
      } 
      completion:^(BOOL finished) {
       appointmentDisplayLbl.alpha = 0.0;
      }];

Comment: please just read my answer again. you did not use the animation options i suggested. also you do *not* need that completion block.

Answer (score 0):

it repeat animation in label

```
-(void)animate
{

[UIView animateWithDuration:1
                          delay:0
                        options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{
                        //set animations
                     } 
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
[self performSelector:@selector(animate) withObject:frdctrl afterDelay:1];
                     }];

}
```